# FuelUX Wizard component - how to allow user to go directly to the last step?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, wizard, fuelux

FuelUX Wizard component - how to allow user to go directly to the last step??

I'm able work with FuelUX Wizard but my need is i want first and last button with next and previous.

i am trying this example

http://bootply.com/74471

any help on this please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example to allow moving a wizard to the last step.  This is presented as a utility function because the wizard itself doesn't (yet?) have this method.

```
function wizardMoveLast($wizard) {
    var $steps = $wizard.find('.steps li');
    var currentStep = $steps.filter('.active').index() + 1;
    var distance = $steps.length - currentStep;

    for (var i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
        $wizard.wizard('next');
    }
}

wizardMoveLast($('#MyWizard'));
```

Comment: hi i have one more issue with it. can u help me out plz

Answer (score 0):

And here is a second example:

> var $total = $('#my-wizard').find('li').length;
>
> $('#my-wizard').wizard('selectItem', { step: $total });